# How to convert C code to Java - Pointer equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c, pointers, equivalent

I am converting some C code into Java which includes image processing. However, I am stuck in a situation where I have to convert some lines of codes which include pointer calculations:

```
for(i=xMin[k];i<=xMax[k];i++)
{
        for(j=yMin[k];j<=yMax[k];j++)
        {
             if (Bimg[i][j]== k1)
             {
                /* accessing single channel for r g b  value */   

                b = data[i*step + j*channels + 0];
                g = data[i*step + j*channels + 1];
                r = data[i*step + j*channels + 2];
             }       
       }              
}
```

Can anybody please tell me how to convert this "data" pointer into java equivalent? Here, "data" is a pointer variable.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716041/java-pointers-equivalent

Answer (score 1):

What is data pointing at?

It looks like it is pointing to an array of bytes, so just make data a `byte[]`. Assuming the C array pointed at and the Java array referred to have the same data, the same calculations should work.

Comment: No, the data variable is pointing at BytePointer

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `data` you specific in the question is actually an array of `unsigned char`. Like:

```
unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*)malloc(datasize*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

I believe the equivalent in java is

```
byte[] data = new byte[datasize]
```

And since java don't allow you to operate pointer. You should use index to manipulate the `data` array.

Note: `byte` in java is always **signed**.
You can get the unsigned value by:

```
int v = b & 0xFF
```